# How to delete all dynamically generated elements at once in a antd Form

Tags: javascript, reactjs, forms, dynamic, antd

If we have a component like this and we want to remove all generated elements at once (like reset the form elemets) how can i achive this by not removing elements from the DOM? The best approach should be to manipulate the "fields" directly, but how can we achive that?

```
import React, { useState, useContext } from 'react';
import { PlusOutlined, MinusOutlined } from '@ant-design/icons';
import { Button, Form } from 'antd';

const App = () => {
  const [form] = Form.useForm();

  const removeQuery = (event, key) => {
    //How to remove all fields in fields?
  };

  return (
    <Form
      form={form}
      name="dynamic_form_nest_item"
      autoComplete="off"
      preserve={false}
    >
      <Form.List name="filterattribute">
        {(fields, { add, remove }) => (
          <div>
            <div>
              <Form.Item>
                <Button
                  type="dashed"
                  onClick={() => add()}
                  block
                  icon={<PlusOutlined />}
                  size="large"
                >
                  Add Element
                </Button>
              </Form.Item>
            </div>
            <div className="greybg" style={{ padding: '6px 0px 8px' }}>
              {fields.map(({ key, name, ...restField }) => (
                <div
                  key={key}
                  style={{
                    display: 'flex',
                    marginTop: 0,
                    justifyContent: 'center',
                  }}
                >
                  <MinusOutlined
                    key={key}
                    style={{ margin: '5px 15px -4px 0px', cursor: 'pointer' }}
                    onClick={(e) => {
                      remove(name);
                      removeQuery(e, key);
                    }}
                  />
                  Element
                </div>
              ))}
            </div>
          </div>
        )}
      </Form.List>
    </Form>
  );
};
export default App;
```

Here's a working example in Stackblitz:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ts-a8fmfb?file=App.tsx

Comment: You can assign emty array to form list. I'll clear all the data. `form.setFieldsValue({ filterattribute: [] })`.

Comment: Thanks, yes this would work. Unfortunately, this does not give us full control over "fields". So if we want to check how many elements are added, how can we achive that?

Comment: You can get the value by using `form.getFieldValue('filterattribute')`. Then check if it's an array `if(Array.isArray(form.getFieldValue('filterattribute')))`, then you can get the length or whatever you want to do with that value.